# Tinymce editor type in Typescript (Unexpected any)

Tags: tinymce

Eslint gives me the error
`Unexpected any. Specify a different type.`

What type should I put in the tinymce editor? I can't find the answer anywhere.

```
window.tinymce.init({
    setup(editor: any) {
        ...
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `editor: Editor`, per the published Typescript types here: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-dist/blob/5.8.2/tinymce.d.ts#L1320